# I want to find Java program to count the occurrence of each character in a string without using Hashmap or array concept

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Synxf.png)

```java
package com.stringprogramdemo;

public class OccuranceOfCharacterIngeneral {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
    String str="Reshma Raghunath Bangar";
    int count=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
    
        for(int j=i;j<str.length();j++) {
            if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j)) {
            count++;    
            }else {
                
            }
            //System.out.println("Total number of count of occurance of "+str.charAt(i)+" is "+count);
        }
        System.out.println("Total number of count of occurance of "+str.charAt(i)+" is "+count);
    }
    
}
}
```

Output:

```
Total number of count of occurance of R is 2
Total number of count of occurance of e is 3
Total number of count of occurance of s is 4
Total number of count of occurance of h is 7
Total number of count of occurance of m is 8
Total number of count of occurance of a is 13
Total number of count of occurance of   is 15
Total number of count of occurance of R is 16
Total number of count of occurance of a is 20
Total number of count of occurance of g is 22
Total number of count of occurance of h is 24
Total number of count of occurance of u is 25
Total number of count of occurance of n is 27
Total number of count of occurance of a is 30
Total number of count of occurance of t is 31
Total number of count of occurance of h is 32
Total number of count of occurance of   is 33
Total number of count of occurance of B is 34
Total number of count of occurance of a is 36
Total number of count of occurance of n is 37
Total number of count of occurance of g is 38
Total number of count of occurance of a is 39
Total number of count of occurance of r is 40
```

Comment: ok, what's the problem?

Comment: You never reset your `count` variable inside the loop when you are done with a character, so it just keeps adding up.

Comment: Please add a more clear description what you want to achieve, what you have already done and what is the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
String str="Reshma Raghunath Bangar";

for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
    int count=0; // move count to here so it counts from zero every iteration of outer loop
    for(int j=i;j<str.length();j++) {
        if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j)) {
            count++;    
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Total number of count of occurance of "+str.charAt(i)+" is "+count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class App {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String str=" Reshma Raghunath Bangar";
        String completed = "";
        for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++) {
            int count=0; 
            for(int j=i; j<str.length();j++) {
                if(str.charAt(i)==str.charAt(j)) {
                    count++;   
                }
            }
            String s = String.valueOf(str.charAt(i));
            if(!completed.contains(s)){
                completed=completed+str.charAt(i);
                System.out.println("Total number of count of occurance of "+str.charAt(i)+" is "+count);
            }         
        }
    }
}
```